# define a variable inside procedure

Tags: scheme, lisp

Can I define a variable inside a procedure? It seems to me I can only define another procedure inside procedures. I came up with this question while doing exercises from SICP and `(rand)` is not what I want because it generates two different random numbers, while I want a same number in those two positions.

```lisp
(define (try x)
    (define (rand) (+ 1 (random (- x 1))))
    (= (rand) (expmod (rand) x x)))
```

---

I have included codes of `expmod` below.

```lisp
(define % remainder)
(define (square a) (* a a))
(define (even? a) (= (% a 2) 0) )
(define (expmod base pow mod)
    (cond 
        ((= pow 0) 
         1)
        ((even? pow) 
         (% (square (expmod base (/ pow 2) mod)) mod))
        (else 
         (% (* base (expmod base (- pow 1) mod) ) mod))))
```

Comment: Did you try `(define rand ...`?

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm really sure the last time I tried it didn't work, but now it works. Maybe I fixed some parenthesis issues when trying `let`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course you can.  In particular

```
(define (x ...) ...)
```

is just a shorthand for

```
(define x (lambda (...) ...))
```

So you are *already defining a variable*: `rand`, whose value is a function.

What you probably want is:

```
(define (try x)
  (define rand (+ 1 (random (- x 1)))
  (= rand (expmod rand x x)))
```

Which in turn is the same as

```
(define (try x)
  (let ([rand (+ 1 (random (- x 1)))])
    (= rand (expmod rand x x))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

```
(define (try x)
  (define rand (+ 1 (random (- x 1))))
  (= rand (expmod rand x x)))
```

You also have to know that `=` and `try` also are variables and they evaluate to procedures. Usually a procedure is created like this:

```
(define double (lambda (n) (+ n n)))
```

However there is a short way to write itL

```
(define (double n) (+ n n))
```

Now look at your code. Aren't you creating a variable `rand` to a lambda with the short syntax?

```
(define (rand) (+ 1 (random (- x 1))))
```

evaluating `rand` should give you some sort of procedure output like `#<procedure: rand>` and calling it `(rand)` will execute `(+ 1 (random (- x 1)`. These kind of procedures are called thunks and are typically used to delay evaluation.

One thing you cannot do in Scheme is to define a top level variable from a procedure. eg.

```
(define (make-test v)
  (define test v))
(make-test 5)
(displayln test) ; unbound variable
```

The reason is that in a procedure it will always make a local binding that only lives inside that closure. One could define a top level variable and then set it:

```
(define test 0) ; make a top level variable
(define (update-test v)
  ;; since no other that top level is named test, 
  ;; that is the binding this is updating. 
  (set! test v)) 
(update-test 5)
(display test) : prints 5
```

Answer (score -1):

```lisp
(define (try x)
  (define rand (+ 1 (random (- x 1))))
  (= (rand) (expmod (rand) x x)))

(define (try x)
  (let ((rand (+ 1 (random (- x 1)))))
    (= (rand) (expmod (rand) x x))))
```

Either of these works.

Comment: Is `rand` a function or a variable? How do you use it? Did you try your code?